# SSRS issue : The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: reporting-services

I'm experiencing an error with SSRS reports executed that take over 1 minute to return data.  This is a sporadic error i.e. sometimes the reports fail but sometimes they run.  This is only for manually executed reports, subscriptions work fine.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The specified network name is no longer available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070040)

This is pointing me to Networking issues obviously.

We do have a separate box providing traffic management features and HTTPS - the actual SSRS box is running HTTP.

I wonder if anyone has seen this error?

Comment: Sounds like a timeout issue. Try to increase timeout in connection string

Comment: I can't see any docs for adding time out to connection string.  For instance, how do we add time out to  : Data Source=localhost\MSSQL13.<InstanceName>; Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following setting in the report -> Properties -> Execution:

[image]

If it doesn't help try to increase to 10000 and see if it makes any change

Comment: I've tried that.  It has no effect.  In fact tried all time out settings.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by limitations in the Traffic Manager.

Comment: I know this was almost 6 years ago at this point so chances are slim that you will know.  But can you expand on what actually caused the issue and how you fixed it.  We have the exact setup that you are describing above with SSRS using http on the backend and https when served to the client.  If the report runs longer than 30 seconds the client gets a 503 or 401 error displayed on the screen.   We have also tried every timeout setting that we could find.  The backend logs of SSRS show that the client disconnected but they didn't.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.